# Listar dados da tabela e atribuir valor a cada um deles (SQL)

Tags: sql

Bom dia! Gostaria de saber como eu faço para listar os dados de um tabela e atribuir valor a cada um deles! Exemplo:

Tabela: personagem
Colunas: ID e nome

Gostaria de pegar todos os nomes que possuem o mesmo id, e listar eles numa página cada um com um com o valor de seu próprio nome! Não sei se ficou claro :x
Aguardo Respostas.

Comment: Como é possível vários usuários terem a mesma ID ?

Comment: Porque está id é no caso a ID da conta, entãoi uma conta pode ter vários personagens entende? :D

Comment: Okay, ainda não entendi completamente :/, mas vou escrever um código.

Comment: Tipo assim vou explicar melhor: Cada conta de usuário tem uma account_id. Porém, cada conta pode ter mais de um personagem, que vão ser salvos com o id da account_id para saber a que conta estão atrelados, porém com o nome do personagem que for. Exemplo: Conta account_id 1 com os personagens jogador 1 e jogador 2. O que eu quero fazer, é listar todos os jogadores atribuidos a uma conta e aplicar neles a id e o name de seus próprios nomes, ou seja, jogador e jogador 2 para que eu possa fazer alterações na coluna de cada um. Não sei se ficou mais claro agora :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Olá, seria algo assim ?**

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM personagens where id_usuario={$id_usuario_logado}";

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao_sqli, $sql);

$id = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
    $id .= $row->id . ",";
}

$id = substr($id, 0 , -1);

$sql = "SELECT usuario FROM personagens WHERE id IN({$id})";

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao_sqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
    echo $row->usuario ."<br/>";
}
```